# GC dump analysis using GCViewer

Tags: java, memory, memory-leaks, garbage-collection, memory-leak-detector

I am analyzing my gc log using GCviewer. I couldn't get better tutorial to understand the GCviewer option. kindly explain me the below option and share me the GCViewer tutorails.

I found below mentioned option in Memory tab of GCViewer

```
Total heap(useage/alloc. max) 1,956.9M(95.7%) /2,044M 
 1. Is it current status of my heap size or maxmium reached heap size?  

Tenured heap (useage/alloc. max) 1,355M/1,060M 
 2. what is Tenured heap?

 3.What is Young Heap?
 4. Avg after full GC?
 5. Freed by Full GC?
 6. Freed by GC?
 7. Avg promotion?
 8. Total Promotion?
```

Answer (score 0):

> I couldn't get better tutorial to understand the GCviewer option"

Those stats are not specific to GCViewer, since it's merely a visualization tool for GC log files.

Instead you should look for explanations of the underlying garbage collectors and their log output.

Note that the structure of the heaps and the stats that the logs produce may differ depending on the garbage collector algorithm used.

Here are a few starting points:

- https://blogs.oracle.com/jonthecollector/entry/our_collectors
- http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/java/gc01/index.html
- https://blogs.oracle.com/jonthecollector/entry/the_unspoken_cms_and_printgcdetails
- http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/gc-tuning-6-140523.html